# Unable to obtain LinkedIn Access Token using Authorization Code

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am unable to obtain a LinkedIn Access Token. My setup is as follows:

1. I have setup an app on LI with this redirect URL `http://localhost:5000/home`
2. I request authorization from LI and get a response with the 'code'.
3. In under 10 seconds, I copy the code query param out of the URL bar and paste it into Postman.
4. In Postman, I have a setup as follows:

   ```
   POST /oauth/v2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.linkedin.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   grant_type=authorization_code&
   client_id=<client id>&
   client_secret=<client secret>&
   redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fhome&
   code=AQSbUzcWwSk_3sqQfusRZWEa4tZqU_x4fSQKub9c3eoeCzZwNO2ZH8uAzJc-T0T40WRv6qNxNpCDxckEjuXHqb56ZhKQqReB5mDjm1kZrCrLlBBYhzyymF5oRzwNgObylJukUVQ_0OiSuE0W0RQ
   ```

I have made multiple attempts but in response, I get the following error.

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"}
```

We have a LI login deployment that suddenly stopped working and started returning this error. On simplifying the use case, I find that Postman does the same.

What gives? What am I doing wrong? This used to work!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @Goat? I have this exact issue

Comment: @Goat Did you get the solution?

Comment: Same issue here. Microsoft, what a wonderful company :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, it fixed itself at the time. It was a LinkedIn issue. Turned out we were doing nothing wrong.

Comment: Any solution guys?

Comment: It's likely a LinkedIn issue. It'll resolve itself.